# Set public value in an object using PHP

Tags: php, oop, methods, static, public

I want to set my value in object using public method. But I can't find to make it work

```
<?php
        class User{
            public $id;

            public function ToSynchData(){
                $this->$id = "1";
            }
        }
        $new = new User;
        $new->ToSynchData();
        $new->$id;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public $id;

public function ToSynchData(){
    $this->id = 1;
}

$new = new User;
$new->ToSynchData();
echo $new->id; // 1
```

EDIT:
Why static all of a sudden?

Comment: What da! Men it works! But I really wonder I tried that a couple of times but it doesn't work. thanks

Comment: Please accept if it works. :) (Click the V under the down arrow)

Comment: Oh and by the way, your problem was the way you referred to the variables. It's $this->var, not $this->$var.

Comment: see the access modifier. it `public` only whereas OP has `static public`

Comment: It *was* just public, he modified his post.

Answer (score 2):

```
class User{
    public $id;
    public function ToSynchData(){
        $this->id = "1";
    }
}

$new = new User();
$new->ToSynchData();
print_r($new->id);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access **static property** with `->` whereas it is clearly written [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

> Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the
>   arrow operator ->.

therefore to access it you have to change it from `static public` to `public`